# How massive can a carbon planet be?

Tags: exoplanet

A [carbon planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_planet) is a theoretical type of planet with more carbon than oxygen. How massive can a carbon planet be? Could you have a neptune-like planet except with all the water replaced with hydrocarbons?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0504214

Comment: Seems to me that, unless you limit planetary formation to specific sequences,  there's no reason to assume the existence of oxygen in the "dust" which agglomerated to produce the planet.  What is the real question that should be asked here?